# updating tags in svn

Tags: svn, svn-copy

If I use `svn copy` to take a snapshot of a portion of a repository, how can I update that snapshot?

Use case:

```
myrepo/
  trunk/
    src/
      something.c
      something.h
  tags/
  branches/
```

`mkdir branches/user1/trusted`

`svn add branches/user1/`

`svn copy trunk/src branches/user1/trusted`

```
myrepo/
  trunk/
    src/
      something.c
      something.h
  tags/
  branches/
    user1/
      trusted/
        src/
          something.c
          something.h
```

--- commits and changes happen in `trunk/src/something.*` here ---

```
myrepo/
  trunk/
    src/
      neatstuff.c           // new file
      something.c           // modified
      big_ugly_include.h    // was something.h, it got renamed
  tags/
  branches/
    user1/
      trusted/
        src/
          something.c
          something.h
```

Now I want branches/user1/trusted/src to be the latest version of trunk/src. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this operation is called `merge`. The [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) covers it in detail.

*edit with a bit more detail:*

As Rob and sgreeve mention, deleting and recreating the branch is another option.  I suggested merge because your example had you creating a branch - the purpose of which is concurrent modification.  If your repository copies aren't to be modified after they're created, you're best off to create a tag rather than a branch.

Comment: Specifically, this section of the book deals with your scenario.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to merging, if you're simply after a straightforward tag update, you could delete the copy and re-create it.

Comment: I agree: it's only worth doing a merge if the files under /branches are being updated in parallel with updates being made to the trunk. If you literally want to take a snapshot of the trunk, better to recreate the branch using svn copy.